# How to make async in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

In my async function, I can't get true priority output.

Expected result is firstly `{control : 1}` and then `{control : 2}`.

But the result is vice versa.

How can I make it true ?

**NodeJS Code**

```
edit_settings = async function (params) {

    await User.updateOne({ _id: params.id }, query, (error, update_result) => {
        console.log({ control : 1 });
        if (error) return { success: false, error: { code: 1001 } };
        else return { success: update_result.nModified };
    });

    return await { control : 2 };
}
```

**NodeJS Result**

```
{ control : 2 }
{ control : 1 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like `User.updateOne` returns a promise (could be wrong, but I'm guessing it doesn't), it accepts a callback, so `await`-ing it will do nothing.

EDIT: One way to solve it is to create a promise like this:

```
edit_settings = async function (params) {
    let res; // the `resolve` method of a promise
    const p = new Promise(r => res = r);
    User.updateOne({ _id: params.id }, query, (error, update_result) => {
        console.log({ control : 1 });
        res(); // resolve the promise
        if (error) return { success: false, error: { code: 1001 } };
        else return { success: update_result.nModified };
    });

    await p;
    return { control: 2 };
}
```

EDIT: Based on your comment that `User.updateOne` actually does return a promise, then you should be using it like this:

```
edit_settings = async function (params) {

    await User.updateOne({ _id: params.id }, query);
    console.log({control:1});
    return { control : 2 };
}
```

From the code you've shown, you actually aren't doing anything with the value you're returning from the promise, so I removed it from your code.

Comment: Does your first example even work? You never assign `res`. Seems like it would be less confusing to just wrap the callback completely in the promise (e.g. `await new Promise(res => User.updateOne(...))`)

Comment: @JakeHolzinger - you're correct, typed it out too fast. I edited to show the reassignment. I also agree with your point, I think it'd be cleaner to just put the whole thing inside a promise rather than my capturing of the resolver. When will they just create a native freaking `Deferred` object? :)

Comment: A deferred object would certainly fit the solution more nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solition:

```
edit_settings = async function (params) {

    let result;

    ..

    result = await User.updateOne({ _id: params.id }, query).then(update_result => {
        result = { success: update_result.nModified };
    });

    ..

    return await result ;
}
```

Comment: You're grossly misunderstanding how `async/await` works. Why would you `return await { control: 2 }`? It's not a promise, it's a value (meaning `return { control: 2}` would accomplish the exact same thing as `return await { control: 2 }`.

Comment: @Adam Yes, you are right. I updated my answer before I see your comment. Thanks btw.

Comment: Super! So it does return a promise. The thing is, you're still misunderstanding `await`. `await` essentially `unwraps` a promise and, while it doesn't break anything, it's terribly confusing to use `await` and `then` next to each other. Do this:

`const result = await User.updateOne(...); console.log({control:1}); return { control: 2 };`

Comment: I got this usage of `async-await`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would console.log blindly. Maybe 
`if (result) return {control:1} 
else return {control:2}`